# Access usb device from systemd-nspawn container

Tags: usb, container, systemd-nspawn

I want to access special USB device (not a simple flash drive) from inside container. 
I bind `/dev/bus/usb` inside container, `lsusb` lists USBs effortlessly:

```
$ lsusb
...
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0a89:0009 
...
```

but my program can't interact with this device.

Answer (score 14):

`systemd-nspawn` handles permissions for devices through [cgroups][1]. By default, any container is granted with permissions only for common devices like `/dev/null`, `/dev/zero`, etc, and additionally to any device passed directly to `--bind` argument like `--bind=/dev/vcs`. This won't work with USB because `/dev/bus/usb` is a directory.

To grant permission for currently running container named `my_container` (supposedly you started it with `systemd-nspawn` directly from command line) execute as root:

```
$ echo 'c 189:* rwm' > \
 /sys/fs/cgroup/devices/machine.slice/machine-my_container/devices.allow
```

`c 189:* rwm` means **r**ead **w**rite **m**knod permissions for any character device with type (identificator) 189 and any subtype.
See also: https://kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/cgroup-v1/devices.html
You can find type and subtype of device with `file`:

```
$ file /dev/bus/usb/002/002
```

This permission will only last while container is running.

If you are using `systemd-nspawn@.service` or want to persist permissions with it, create

```
/etc/systemd/system/systemd-nspawn@.service.d/override.conf
```

or

```
/etc/systemd/system/systemd-nspawn@my_container.service.d/override.conf
```

(depending on whether you want access to USB from any `systemd-nspawn` container or only from `my_container` correspondingly) with the following content:

```
[Service]
DeviceAllow=char-usb_device rwm
```

`usb_device` is an alias. You can find other in `/proc/devices`.
[1]: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/cgroups

Comment: Just to add, you still need to add the file/directory to the `systemd-nspawn` command in a `--bind` argument.

Comment: The `m` flag is for `mknod`, not **m**odify. See: https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/cgroup-v1/devices.html