# systemd-nspawn: how to allow access to all devices?

Tags: systemd, docker, devices, container, systemd-nspawn

I'm trying to create a rough equivalent of Docker's `--privileged` in a systemd container, but I've got no idea how to allow the container to access all of the devices available on the host (without manually enumerating them).

I came across [Access usb device from systemd-nspawn container](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/304252/access-usb-device-from-systemd-nspawn-container) and a nice `--privileged` description at https://github.com/rkt/rkt/issues/2962#issuecomment-235444606 , but I don't know how to put the bits together.

I also tried the naive `--bind=/dev` but this way there was no standard output and the container never started.

Any hints how to handle this?

Comment: Did you end up finding a solution to your problem? I've asked a slightly different question here: [How can I make an additional device available inside a systemd-nspawn container with user namespacing?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/557293/how-can-i-make-an-additional-device-available-inside-a-systemd-nspawn-container)