# How can I make a device available inside a systemd-nspawn container with user namespacing?

Tags: users, namespace, container, bind-mount, systemd-nspawn

I would like to mount an encrypted image file using `cryptsetup` inside a [`systemd-nspawn`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-nspawn.html) container. However, I get this error message:

```
[root@container ~]# echo $key | cryptsetup -d - open luks.img luks
Cannot initialize device-mapper. Is dm_mod kernel module loaded?
Cannot use device luks, name is invalid or still in use.
```

The `dm_mod` kernel module is loaded on the host system, although things look a bit weird inside the container:

```
[root@host ~]# grep dm_mod /proc/modules
dm_mod 159744 2 dm_crypt, Live 0xffffffffc12c6000

[root@container ~]# grep dm_mod /proc/modules
dm_mod 159744 2 dm_crypt, Live 0x0000000000000000
```

`strace` indicates that `cryptsetup` is unable to create `/dev/mapper/control`:

```
[root@etrial ~]# echo $key | strace cryptsetup -d - open luks.img luks 2>&1 | grep mknod
mknod("/dev/mapper/control", S_IFCHR|0600, makedev(0xa, 0xec)) = -1 EPERM (Operation not permitted)
```

I am not too sure why this is happening. I am starting the container with [the `systemd-nspawn@.service` template unit](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/master/units/systemd-nspawn%40.service.in), which seems like it should allow access to the device mapper:

```
# nspawn can set up LUKS encrypted loopback files, in which case it needs
# access to /dev/mapper/control and the block devices /dev/mapper/*.
DeviceAllow=/dev/mapper/control rw
DeviceAllow=block-device-mapper rw
```

Reading [this comment on a related question about USB devices](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/304252/access-usb-device-from-systemd-nspawn-container#comment740952_304253), I wondered whether the solution was to add a bind mount for `/dev/mapper`. However, `cryptsetup` gives me the same error message inside the container. When I `strace` it, it looks like there's still a permissions issue:

```
# echo $key | strace cryptsetup open luks.img luks --key-file - 2>&1 | grep "/dev/mapper"
stat("/dev/mapper/control", {st_mode=S_IFCHR|0600, st_rdev=makedev(0xa, 0xec), ...}) = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/dev/mapper/control", O_RDWR) = -1 EACCES (Permission denied)

# ls -la /dev/mapper
total 0
drwxr-xr-x 2 nobody nobody      60 Dec 13 14:33 .
drwxr-xr-x 8 root   root       460 Dec 15 14:54 ..
crw------- 1 nobody nobody 10, 236 Dec 13 14:33 control
```

Apparently, this is happening because the template unit enables user namespacing, which I want anyway for security reasons. As explained in the [documentation](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-nspawn.html):

> In most cases, using `--private-users=pick` is the recommended option as it enhances container security massively and operates fully automatically in most cases ... [this] is the default if the `systemd-nspawn@.service` template unit file is used ...
>
> Note that when [the `--bind` option] is used in combination with `--private-users`, the resulting mount points will be owned by the `nobody` user. That's because the mount and its files and directories continue to be owned by the relevant host users and groups, which do not exist in the container, and thus show up under the wildcard UID 65534 (`nobody`). If such bind mounts are created, it is recommended to make them read-only, using `--bind-ro=`.

Presumably I won't be able to do anything with read-only permissions to `/dev/mapper`. So, is there any way I can get `cryptsetup` to work inside the container, so that my application can create and mount arbitrary encrypted volumes at runtime, without disabling user namespacing?

### Related questions

- [systemd-nspawn: file-system permissions for a bound folder](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/393584/systemd-nspawn-file-system-permissions-for-a-bound-folder/465391#465391) relates to files rather than devices, and the only answer just says that "`-U` is mostly incompatible with rw `--bind`."
- [systemd-nspawn: how to allow access to all devices](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/492353/systemd-nspawn-how-to-allow-access-to-all-devices) doesn't deal with user namespacing and there are no answers.

Answer (score 0):

It might be that you are missing the `m` permission. What happens if you specify `rwm` insteadof `rw` on at least your first `DeviceAllow`?